# Xcode 4.5 "Apply retina 4 Form factor" toggle button not working properly

Tags: xcode, ios6

I'm trying to update an IOS app for IOS6 and iPhone 5, but I have a problem resizing some views from the main Storyboard.

When I click on the new "Apply Retina 4 Form Factor" button, some of the views included in the StoryBoard don´t resize. I´ve checked all the settings for every Scene and seem to be configured in the same way. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your code look like? Please add it to your question.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might have found your solution but I just had a similar problem. For future notice, I found the fix was in the show size inspector and instead of using layout rectangle, I used frame rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, this answer worked for me and finally removed the letterbox:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12927282/539149

So add a 640x1136 launch image called Default-568h@2x.png and set the "Retina (4-inch)" target setting to it.  More info for the other sizes here:

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html

Just in case it helps others, I had tried these links and none of them got rid of the letterbox, but they did at least enable the resize masks:

[Resize of UIViewController in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728952/resize-of-uiviewcontroller-in-storyboard)

[Xcode 4.5: can't set root view autoresizingMask in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329726/xcode-4-5-cant-set-root-view-autoresizingmask-in-interface-builder)

[how do you resize (visually, not programmatically) the detail view of a UISplitViewController in a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902297/how-do-you-resize-visually-not-programmatically-the-detail-view-of-a-uisplitv)

[iphone 5 and storyboard setting autoresizing masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939580/iphone-5-and-storyboard-setting-autoresizing-masks)